# Why can't I rename a shared library after it's been built?

Tags: macos

Here's a simple example:

**lib.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello_world(void) {
  puts("Hello, world!");
}
```

**program.c:**

```
void hello_world(void);

int main() {
  hello_world();
  return 0;
}
```

If I compile the library normally and link it, everything works fine:

```
$ cc lib.c -fPIC -shared -o libmylib.dylib
$ cc program.c -L. -lmylib
$ ./a.out
Hello, world!
```

But if I rename the library after building it (but before building the program), it doesn't work:

```
$ cc lib.c -fPIC -shared -o totally_different_name.dylib
$ mv totally_different_name.dylib libmylib.dylib
$ cc program.c -L. -lmylib
$ ./a.out
dyld: Library not loaded: totally_different_name.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/tmp/./a.out
  Reason: image not found
[1]    13229 abort      ./a.out
```

Why is this the case? Why is dyld looking for the original library name?

This works okay on Linux, but when I try on macOS it completely fails (I don't know if it's a macOS vs Linux thing, or a clang vs gcc thing, since I'm using clang on macOS and gcc on Linux).

If it's relevant, `cc --version` is `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0`.

Comment: Does `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out` make a difference?

Comment: @dhke: No, and not for `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` either.

Comment: `otool -L ./a.out` should give you the list of dependencies the program declares. At least that might help narrowing down the problem.

Comment: On macOS the library also has its own name coded within itself. `otool -L` should show this. The first line is the library itself. You probably have to change this name too with the `install_name_tool`.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch: Indeed, the first line of the output of `otool -L` is the original name of the library. Thanks for the tip of using `install_name_tool`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Florian Zwoch's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877686/why-cant-i-rename-a-shared-library-after-its-been-built#comment72860073_42877686), I was able to find a way to fix this. Run this command after renaming the dylib:

```
install_name_tool -id libmylib.dylib libmylib.dylib
```

That command changes the internal ID of the dylib. The command syntax is `install_name_tool -id <new-id> <dylib-path>`.

Originally, the dylib has the ID of totally_different_name.dylib. Renaming the file doesn't change the ID it has stored internally, and that has to be updated separately with `install_name_tool`.

Comment: My answer shows how to fix the problem, but I lack the depth of knowledge necessary to explain better what's happening and why. If anyone posts an answer that better explains how dylibs work, how clang builds them, how macOS uses them, and why this extra step is necessary, I'll happily accept that answer.